# Run x number of threads in c# loop

Tags: c#

In a console application I am running a parallel for each loop within another loop, but one of my updates might take 10 minutes but the rest only take 1 second. That means that 99 are done but it waits for the 1 remaining to finish before getting the next batch to run.

```
List<Items> myItems = GetItems();
while (myItems.Count > 0)
{
   ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
   options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100;
   Parallel.ForEach(myItems, options, item => {
    CallUpdate(item.ID);
   });

   // Get some more records and loop
   myItems = GetItems()
}
```

Is there a better way to do this so that 100 threads can always be running while some items exist?

Comment: what is the outer while loop for?  What's happening inside GetItems()?

Comment: If task is IO bound have more threads than cores. If CPU bound, have no more threads than cores.

Comment: Why do you care if you are keeping all the threads busy? Do you know which update takes a long time? If you do, schedule it separately (perhaps on a non-thread-pool thread). You may also want to reduce your parallelism (so that the 99 items are done at a more leisurely pace - no need to hurry if you are going to wait anyway). For what it's worth, you're likely to find that you aren't getting work done on all the threads you think you are using

Comment: @MikeJ It just gets batches of items to work on that haven't yet been processed. So instead of getting 10 million items at once it will do it in smaller batches of 100 so that the myItems collection isn't using lots of memory.

Comment: @Flydog57 I don't know which ones will take a long time, it is just an example. The point is that I always want 100 going at one time and sometimes only 1 is.

Comment: @feijoc is it a CPU intensive or I/O intensive processing? e.g. is it waiting on a long running calculation or for a DB callback?

Comment: @kshkarin it's actually a combination of a few things, I've tried to simplify it for the question by not including what it does but there are database updates in there, processing files, api updates etc but they all need to be completed in order and the last step marks it as completed so that it doesn't get picked up in the next batch.

Comment: @feijoc probably best to break it down to each step and apply the appropriate solution, if it's an I/O bound step like waiting for a DB call then use async/await, if it's a CPU intense step then parallelize. Also try to find the bottlenecks without the async or parallel processing - it could give insight as to which steps are taking longer.

Comment: @kshkarin I'm not bothered about the ones that take a long time, I know why and it's valid that they take that amount of time. I just want to fix the other 99 that are sat there doing nothing when they could be processing something.

Comment: @feijoc right, but what's the one that's taking so long doing? without more details it's difficult to suggest or speculate on what's actually happening. Is that 1 long update doing a calculation or waiting for something like a DB INSERT operation?

Comment: You say *"but they all need to be completed in order"*. If you are parallelizing them, there's no guarantee of order. Using `Parallel.ForEach` works best when the things you are parallelizing are similar. As others have noted, you really need to think about whether your units of work are *I/O bound* or *CPU Bound* and treat them differently - they will behave very differently under the covers. How do you monitor to know that *sometimes only1 is [going at the same time]*. Usually, you will get N going at the same time, where N is the # of cores (/virtual cores) on the machine you are running on

Comment: "completed" was a bad choice of wording, they all need to be processed based on a date order that they came in, I don't actually care how long each one takes to process I just want to loop through them all and have 100 being in process at one time. I can see from my code that 99 have finished as they have a db flag set at the end but there is time wasted by these threads being sat there doing nothing until that last ones completed. What actually happens inside GetItems isn't the problem that I have or need to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

What your describing is a pretty good fit for a producer/consumer pattern implementation. You can create a simple implementation of that pattern with a [BlockingCollection](http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-blockingcollection)

But if the complexity grows then something like [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) is probably a better choice.  Here's an example for [producer/consumer using TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern).